# Proper way to define two way relations between two tables

Tags: javascript, bookshelf.js

I have three tables:

```
Employee (emp_id,name)
Projects (pid,proj_status)
Project_Allocation (pid,emp_id)
```

To find the people belonging to my project:
1. I have my name, I query my emp_id.
2. Using my emp_id, I query (withRelated) for all my projects from Project_Allocation (completed ones as well) with a belongsTo relation defined on Projects
3. Then I pick the pid of the project having status as 'LIVE'
4. Now I pick all the models having this pid in Project_allocation.

The issue I'm encountering is when creating the schemas for Project and Project_Allocation tables. The both require each other and I cant load them both. Please suggest how I can rewrite this.

Here are few extracts:

The Project_Allocation file:

```
var Project = require('./project');
var PASchema = Bookshelf.Model.extend({
tableName: 'project_allocation',
project: function(){
    return this.belongsTo(ProjectSchema, 'pid')
}
```

The Project file:

```
var ProjAlloc = require('./projAlloc');
var ProjectSchema = Bookshelf.Model.extend({
tableName: 'project',
idAttribute: 'pid',
allocatedIDs: function() {
    return this.belongsTo(PASchema,'pid')
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with `require`. The deadlock was being caused there. I was defining each of my table in a separate file and `require`-ing them in other table definitions (i.e other files). Writing all my table definitions in a single file and then exporting that object worked fine.