# bookshelf.js many to many relationship not working (belongsToMany)

Tags: node.js, bookshelf.js

I can't get to work a many-to-many relationship using bookshelf.js.

Models:

```
var Event = bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'events',
    idAttribute: 'event_id',
    tags: function() {
        return this.belongsToMany(Tag, 'events_tags', 'event_id', 'tag_id');
    }
});

var Tag = bookshelf.Model.extend({
   tableName: 'tags',
   idAttribute: 'tag_id',
   events: function() {
      return this.belongsToMany(Event, 'events_tags', 'tag_id', 'event_id');
   }
});
```

Database table "events":

```
  event_id      name
 -------------------------------------------------
      1          party at my place
```

Database table "tags":

```
  tag_id         name
 ---------------------------
      1           music
```

Database table "events_tags":

```
  event_tag_id          event_id         tag_id
 -------------------------------------------------------------
      1                   1                 1
```

Query that isn't returning what it should:

```
new db.Event()
.fetchAll({withRelated: ['tags']})
.then(function(events) {

    console.log(events.toJSON());
});
```

The log outputs:

```
 [{'event_id': 1, 'name': 'party at my place', 'tags': []}]
```

That is: empty array of tags, which is wrong.

**Question: Is there an issue with my code?** the desired output should be:

```
 [{
   'event_id': 1, 'name': 'party at my place', 
   'tags': [{'tagId':1, 'name':'music'}]
 }]
```

This doesn't help in the question, but I'll throw it anyway: I'm currently hating all ORMs in Node JS! Maybe I should just use a query builder.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I think it might be related to the cache not being invalid on one object when the attach is done on the corresponding object. I think there's a reload/refresh function, but I can't remember what it's called...

Comment: Can you turn on debugging so we can see the SQL generated for your query? `var knex = require('knex')({ ..., debug: true; }), Bookshelf = require('bookshelf')(knex);`

Answer (score 2):

I think I have a similar issue, and had [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24866820/proper-way-to-define-two-way-relations-between-two-tables) about it. Defining a relationship both ways, i.e one from **Event** to **Tag** and another from **Tag** to **Event** might be creating a deadlock. When the **Event** definition is being executed, it finds the dependency on **Tag** and jumps to execute the definition for **Tag**, inside which there is a dependecy back to **Event**. At this point they both are not created fully.

Comment: This was the concept of the problem I faced with relations not appearing when formatting. It wasn't a circular dependency issue. I got relations to appear by renaming the function name of the relationship on child models. e.g. `Tag.event` would have to become `Tag.parent_event` - as long as the function isn't called `event` it works for me.